# Getting DISTINCT values from a JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, join, distinct

i currently have the following LINQ statement:

```
using (MYEntities ctx = CommonMY.GetMYContext())
{
    List<datUser> lstC = (from cObj in ctx.datUser 
                          join fs in ctx.datFS on cObj.UserID equals fs.datUser.UserID 
                          where userOrg.Contains(fs.userOrg.OrgName)
                          select cObj).ToList();

    foreach (datUser c in lstC)
    {
        Claim x = new Claim
        {
            UserID= c.userID,
            FirstName = c.FirstName,
            LastName = c.LastName,
            MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
        };
    }
}
```

right now it returns all users, but it duplicates them if they have more then 1 org associated with them.
how can i ensure that it only returns distinct UserIDs?

each user can have multiple orgs, but i really just need to return users that have at least 1 org from the userOrg list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before your ToList, put in `.Distinct()`.

In response to @DJ BURB, you should probably use the Distinct overload that takes in an IEqualityComparer to best be sure that you're doing it based off of the unique id of each record.

Look at [this blog post](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IEqualityComparer.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Wouldn't they need to specify which value needs to be distinct?

Comment: In the `Equals()` method of your custom comparer (which should accept 2 variables of the type that `cObj` is above) just compare whatever values you want to to make sure that they are distinct.

Comment: i'm sorry, what Equals() method? is that something i need to add? or do you mean the equals in the join statement?

Comment: I mean in the custom comparer that you can put into the overload for the Distinct method. Check out the blog post that's in the answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

use group by.

syntax:

```
var result= from p in <any collection> group p by p.<property/attribute> into grps
             select new 
             {
               Key=grps.Key,
               Value=grps
             }
```

Comment: so i don't need select cObj).ToList();?

Comment: you'll still need to wrap the whole things in a (var result ..{}).ToList() if that's how you want the end result to be

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx), there is [no linq query equivalent of that command](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx).